# Synergy capitalization using shift key is not working

Tags: shift

My synergy version is 1.4.10 in both server and client.

Server is Windows 10 and client is ubuntu 18.04

Capitalization using caps lock is working and keyboard shortcuts using shift key is working as well.

However when I capitalize using shift key, it doesn't work.

What's the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this problem by upgrading synergy version.

It seems like a bug of version 1.4.10.